# What number is hidden in this card?

Tags: visual

The puzzle below is part of a Puzzle Crime Story I have started on my website, but will skip the details here (you can see other puzzles from the series [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33466/detective-flanders-and-the-zodiac-killer-2) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33534/detective-flanders-and-the-zodiac-killer-3)). In short, you have the following rectangular card which has the word "SIN" written on one side and a bunch of letters/symbols on the other. You must figure out a 4-digit number encoded in the card. I am sharing the puzzle here because I've noticed nobody has figured it out yet and want to decide whether to simplify it a bit.

[image]
front side
[image]
back side (turning the card left-to-right)

Comment: When going from the front to the back, did you flip the card over left-to-right or top-to-bottom?

Comment: Yeah, that's important - left-to-right.

Comment: Answered in less than a couple of hours. I guess there is no need to simplify it? Maybe you just need to add a carefully phrased hint?

Comment: I got sidetracked by reading the N's as Z's (which made the anagram step not work). Up to you whether that's something to change or not.

Comment: @Keale 30 Minutes actually ... This includes creating the post.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The back side is:

> An anagram for `PUNISHMENT`

Rearranging the letters to match transforms the front into the numbers:

> `1713`

The result as a picture

> [image]

Comment: Gah, I was working on images! :(

Comment: @Will Yeah, I'm a computer guy but I figured this one would be faster on paper.

Comment: So... where does greed come into play?

Comment: @Devsman in my story there is a killer who murders his victims for their sins. This particular one has been greedy.

Comment: I think you can assume "Greed" as a hint too. Except its main meaning according to story, it can be the misspelled word "grid", which is a hint for rearranging the paper cells.

Comment: @Puzzle Prime If part of the story depends on "Greed" misspelled as "Grid," (or vice-versa), you might use the fact that "greed" is how a Spanish speaker would pronounce "Grid."  This actually happened to me when I asked a Mexican guest if he would like some of my flat chocolate cake.  "Would you like a piece of this sheet cake?"   . . . pause . . . "**What** kind of cake . . .???""  8-D

Comment: @Rob Actually the greed-grid thing was not planned initially, but ended up as a nice hint. Cool story though:)

Comment: You mention the puzzle is on a website; however, solving it requires printing the card (or redrawing it by hand on paper) and cutting it. Is there any other puzzle on the website that requires drawing and cutting like that? Perhaps your players are expecting to solve the puzzle simply by looking at their screen, without using paper.