# What number is hidden in this gallery?

Tags: visual

This is another chapter from the puzzle crime series I am running on my website (you can find two previous puzzles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/what-password-is-encoded-in-this-card) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33466/detective-flanders-and-the-zodiac-killer)). I asked a real artist to make the illustration for this one and thought it turned out very pretty, so decided to share.

The goal is to find a passcode which is a 4-digit number.

> **7. The Third Body**
>
> Fifteen minutes later Morrow, Flanders, as well as three other police
> officers were in front of the former mayor’s house. It was a large
> building, with its own parking lot, a fountain, and everything you
> could expect from an expensive, luxurious mansion. The five men tried
> to call Phil one last time and when nobody answered, they broke the
> door. It didn’t take them long before they found him lying dead in the
> Claptons’ personal gallery room. He was holding a red rose in his
> hands.

[image]

P.S. The text is mostly to drive the story, focus on the illustration.

P.S.S. I simplified the puzzle a bit - initially the letters on the left spelled "Love".

Comment: Yeah, I also think so. Found a girl on Fiverr which made it for just $25. I know advertising on puzzling is not ideal, but I think she may be of use for other puzzle creators here. That's her profile:
https://www.fiverr.com/worldforlove

Comment: I notice if you XOR L with columns 4-6 and E with columns 9-12, you get the numbers 5 and 7 respectively. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: @JoeZ. you are on the right track, but there is more to it.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that the male and female intersecting on the right side could have been a clue to the pixel XOR overlay; I didn't even think of that when trying the XOR out. :P

Comment: @JoeZ. I expect you to solve the puzzle within 5 minutes now.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Alas, I am not _that_ good at figuring out what to do here.

Comment: At a first glance, I thought this was a pattern to run with Conway's Game of Life :) . Maybe an idea for a future puzzle?

Comment: @GeorgesDuperon, that's indeed a very good idea, I even think there are already few nice puzzles here based on it:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number hidden in the picture is:

> **3274**

Explanation:
After the simplification in the question (the original one featured the word "LOVE" instead of "LUST") this is what I get...

> ...turning upside down the 12x5 panel on the front wall, then using the word LUST as a XOR mask for it:

This is...

> ... **the 12x5 panel, turned upside-down**:
>  [image: Panel upside down]

This is the word I used as...

> ... **XOR mask**:
>  [image: LUST]

...and the result of the...

> ... **XOR operation** is:
>  [image]
>  the number **3274**

Deeper explanation:

> The pictures on the left wall suggest you must "put a 4 letters word on top" of the picture on the front wall.
>  The first picture on the right suggest that you must turn white those squares where 2 black squares take place.
>  The second picture on the right gives a hint on turning upside down the 12x5 panel and on using a word in opposition to LOVE (the word used in the original question instead of LUST)

Comment: This is a much better answer than the other

Comment: What was the clue to change from LOVE to LUST  (I mean before the painting changed)

Comment: @Lordofdark: I added an explanation on what you're asking: the heart upside-down suggested to "turn" LOVE into something with an opposite meaning

Comment: Also, it must not have been love, or else he wouldn't be dead :)

Comment: @Hunter Ok I thought the upside down heart just meant to reverse the letters.

Comment: Yep, that's the correct one it seems. I couldn't find the right word. :S

Comment: Yes, that's right! Just about the pictures - the first on the right suggests to use XOR, the second one suggests that the painting is upside down. About the words "Lust" and "Love" - reading the puzzle story is easy to think of it, but I guess it's hard just from the picture. Not sure what to do with choosing the right answer though - promised it to @JoeZ. since he was very close, but you gave first a thorough explanation...

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan This one belongs to Hunter, since he got the actual word.

Comment: Ok since everyone is happy, will do that. @Hunter - I think if you change the steps to first flipping the big painting (because the flipped heart painting) and then applying XOR (because of the XORed symbols painting), it may be easier to follow.

Comment: @Artur: I'll edit my answer according to your suggestion as soon as possible

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan: updated my solution, hope it's clearer now

Comment: Looks good @Hunter, I just added one detail to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My original partial solution was as follows:

> If you use the "L O V E" at the front as an XOR mask for the 5x12 center image in the orientation "O L Ʌ E", you get:
>
> [image]
>
> which looks like a "6" in negative space, followed by 5, 2, and 7.

Of course, the numbers up there look all *weird* (and one of them is even in negative space) because I actually had the wrong word — the question was edited to make it clearer that the word "LUST" was what we really wanted, since nobody really got that. If we turn that word *completely* upside down and XOR it to the image, we get:

[image]

which is clearly the number "3274" also upside-down.

Comment: Is this on the right track?

Comment: It is definitely on the right track, I would say you are 50% there. If I gave more details from the story, it would have been much easier though.

Comment: I suspect that instead of LOVE you should try its opposite... Maybe HATE? (I tried XORing it with no success, anyway...)

Comment: @Hunter That's also going in the right direction.

Comment: Try swapping black for white in the letters of love.

Comment: @LeppyR64 That's equivalent to flipping an entire 3x5 square. That just turns negative space into positive.

Comment: The pictures on the left suggest that there is some writing on the big painting, the first picture on the right suggests that you must use XOR. What does the second picture on the right suggest though?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, lol

Comment: If I try the word "LOVE" completely upside-down, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/dd6qPK4.png

Comment: @JoeZ. I simplified the puzzle, will accept your answer when you correct it.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan I was asleep when you posted that, so... give it to the other person. :P